# AssertionError None! = Value , while running a unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I need to call a def function "sumin" into a test function "Tests". Please let me know how do I get that done. Below is the error for the code that i am getting.

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test (__main__.Tests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ninjawarrior/miniconda3/environments_files/pythonbasics/CodeWars/7_kyu/functions.py", line 13, in test
    self.assertEquals(sumin(6), 91)
AssertionError: None != 91

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)

Process finished with exit code 1 

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
import numpy as np
import unittest2

def sumin(n):
    arr = np.array([(x, y) for x in range(n + 1) for y in range(n + 1)])
    sum_in = arr.min(axis=1)
    sumofmin = sum_in.sum(axis=0)
    print(sumofmin)


class Tests(unittest2.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEquals(sumin(6), 91) <<<Issue is here ! 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest2.main()

sumin(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `sumin` does not return anything, thus when you call it from your test it says that it is `None`.